# Impossible to reconnect user using OAuth in

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, .net-6.0, quickbooks-online

I'm trying configure an authentication / Authorization process, using OAuth in .NET 6 for QBO (QuickbookOnline) authority.

User successfully go through the process once and is authenticated - everything works fine, all this using CookieAuthenticationDefault and AddOAuth(). Later, user press "Logoff" where I, in backend, call SignOutAsync. I do have to call using Apk from QBO to revoke it's token (this is a, as per my understandings, a requirement in order to been a trusted app using QBO - user must disconnect). All this, works fine; disconnect user thus having its token get revoked.

But, when user try to log back in once again, process goes to the QBO endpoint as per the first time, but when it comes back to my endpoint, I get a "error":"invalid_client". How can it has been through once and done it correctly and not doing it correctly on the second (later) try?

Here is my configuration:

**Startup.cs**

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded=ctx => HostEnvironment.IsProduction();
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy=SameSiteMode.None;
 }).AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie()
   .AddOAuth("qbo",o => {
          o.AuthorizationEndpoint=Configuration["QBO:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
          o.CallbackPath="/signin-qbo";
          o.ClientId=Configuration["QBO:ClientId"];
          o.ClientSecret=Configuration["QBO:ClientSecret"];
          o.TokenEndpoint=Configuration["QBO:TokenEndpoint"];
          o.UserInformationEndpoint=Configuration["QBO:UserInformationEndpoint"];
          o.ClaimsIssuer=Configuration["QBO:ClaimsIssuer"];
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"sub");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name,"givenName");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email,"email");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName,"givenName");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname,"familyName");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("emailVerified","emailVerified");
          o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("realmid","realmid");
          o.SaveTokens=true;
          o.Scope.Clear();
          o.UsePkce=true;

          new string[] { "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting","openid","email","profile" }.ToList().ForEach(s => o.Scope.Add(s));

          o.Events.OnCreatingTicket=async ctx => {
              var accessToken = ctx.AccessToken;
              var refreshToken = ctx.RefreshToken;
              var companyId = ctx.HttpContext.Request.Query["realmid"];

              ctx.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
              ctx.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization=new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",accessToken);

              var response = await ctx.Backchannel.GetStringAsync(ctx.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
              var userInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(response);
              ctx.RunClaimActions(userInfo);

              var id = userInfo.GetString("sub");
              using var applicationContext = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ApplicationContext>();
              var applicationUser = applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.AccountingSystemId==id);

              if(applicationUser==null) {
                 applicationUser=new ApplicationUser {
                    AccountingSystemId=userInfo.GetString("sub"),
                    GivenName=userInfo.GetString("givenName"),
                    Surname=userInfo.GetString("familyName"),
                    Email=userInfo.GetString("email"),
                    EmailVerified=bool.Parse(userInfo.GetString("emailVerified")),
                    CompanyId=companyId,
                    AccessToken=accessToken,
                    RefreshToken=refreshToken
                 };
                 applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.Add(applicationUser);
              } else {
                 applicationUser.AccessToken=accessToken;
                 applicationUser.RefreshToken=refreshToken;
              }
              applicationContext.SaveChanges();
          };
     });
```

**Login/logout**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task SignInQBO(string returnUrl = "/") {
        try {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("qbo",new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri=returnUrl });
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            var s = ex;
        }
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> SignOutQBO() {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var oauthClient = new OAuth2Client(_configuration["QBO:ClientId"],_configuration["QBO:ClientSecret"],new PathString("/"),"sandbox");
        var t = await oauthClient.RevokeTokenAsync(usr.RefreshToken);

        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to compare the auth URLs between the first and second attempts? In my experience "invalid_client" can mean a lot of things, but i suspect it could be that the auth URL contains a unauthorised redirect uri

Comment: @NickMaxwell yes, but I know it's not the problem here as user is prompt in qbo endpoint to autorize my app, and then send back to my callback /signin-qbo, but then crash on my side. Anyhow, how it was able to log once, but not the second time?

Comment: I think it's possible for the server to return invalid_client even after the consent phase. I can see that you are redirecting to /Index after logout, but the default returnUrl on sign in is just /, if the client is passing /Index to that action that would result in invalid_client if not configured on the auth server. I can only suggest to check the redirect uri in the address you are taken to when the qb login appears, or just add /Index to the allowed uris or change the logout redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding here is *not correct*:

```
I do have to call using Apk from QBO to revoke it's token (this is a, as 
per my understandings, a requirement in order to been a trusted app using
QBO - user must disconnect)
```

You do *not* need to disconnect from QBO when the user logs off. In fact, you *should not* be doing this, and won't pass your app review if you do.

The only time you should be revoking the token is if the user *specifically clicks a button in your app telling you to disconnect your app from QuickBooks*. e.g. they are clicking a button labeled `[Disconnect from QuickBooks]`.

Just logging off does *not* require a disconnect/token revoke.

Comment: Allright then, knowing that, why then when user has logged off (simply a  HttpContext.Signout) and tried to log back in, I get the error: Invalid Client (without revoking its token)?